# Запуск программы для Arduino с SD карты на Ардуино

Tags: arduino, микроконтроллеры

Возможно ли запустить прошивку\программу специально собранную под Arduino с SD карты? Какими средствами это делается?

Comment: Где запустить? В эмуляторе?

Comment: @0andriy нет, на самой Arduino

Comment: На самой плате должен быть загрузчик — что угодно, что сможет загрузить и запустить вашу программу. Без этого никак. Процессоры умеют выполнять код из памяти только.

Answer (score 0):

Именно на ардуино точно не получится.
Теоретически возможно написать загрузчик для AVR микроконтроллера, который будет считывать скомпилированную программу с SD карты и записывать ее в память программ микроконтроллера. Но скорее всего, такой загрузчик займет много места в памяти программ и, соответственно, останется мало места для основной программы.